# Tensorflow RNN placeholder value error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I've been trying to follow up on [RNN using Tensorflow](https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/hello-world-rnn-83cd7105b767). It's a simple program but somehow unable to run on TF v1.5

I've tried to follow the tutorial to the fullest, and also tried checking out the comments section, but to no avail.

Somehow I'm not being able to figure out where to fix the problem.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')


print('Tensorflow Version: %s' % tf.__version__)


# number of iterations 
num_epochs = 1000

total_series_length = 50000

truncated_backprop_length = 15

state_size = 4 

num_classes = 2 

echo_step = 3

batch_size = 5

num_batches = total_series_length//batch_size//truncated_backprop_length


def generate_data():
    x = np.array(np.random.choice(2, total_series_length, p=[0.5, 0.5]))
    y = np.roll(x, echo_step)

    x = x.reshape(batch_size, -1)
    y = y.reshape(batch_size, -1)

    return x, y


batchX_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, truncated_backprop_length])
batchY_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [batch_size, truncated_backprop_length])


# RNN state, saved output from the previous run
init_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, state_size])


W = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(state_size+1, state_size), dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros((1, state_size)), dtype=tf.float32)


W2 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(state_size, num_classes), dtype=tf.float32)
b2 = tf.Variable(np.zeros((1, num_classes)), dtype=tf.float32)


input_series = tf.unstack(batchX_placeholder, axis=1)
labels_series = tf.unstack(batchY_placeholder, axis=1)


# forward pass
current_state = init_state

state_series = []

for current_input in input_series:
    current_input = tf.reshape(current_input, [batch_size, 1])
    # Increasing number of columns
    input_and_state_concatenated = tf.concat(values=[current_input, current_state], axis=1)


    # Broadcasted addition 
    next_state = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(input_and_state_concatenated, W) + b)
    state_series.append(next_state)
    current_state = next_state



# Broacast addition
logits_series = [tf.matmul(state, W2) + b2 for state in state_series]
prediction_series = [tf.nn.softmax(logits) for logits in logits_series]

losses = [tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels) for logits, labels in zip(logits_series, labels_series)]
total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)

train_step = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.3).minimize(total_loss)




def plot(loss_list, prediction_series, batchX, batchY):
    plt.subplot(2, 3, 1)
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(loss_list)

    for batch_series_idx in range(5):
        one_hot_output_series = np.array(prediction_series)[:,batch_series_idx, :]
        single_output_series = np.array([(1 if out[0]<0.5 else 0) for out in one_hot_output_series])

        plt.subplot(2, 3, batchY + 2)
        plt.cla()
        plt.axix(0, truncated_backprop_length, 0, 2)
        left_offset = range(truncated_backprop_length)
        plt.bar(left_offset, batchX[batch_series_idx, :], width=1, color='blue')
        plt.bar(left_offset, batchY[batch_series_idx, :] * 0.5, width=1, color='red')
        plt.bar(left_offset, single_output_series * 0.3, width=1, color='green')

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)



with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    plt.ion()
    plt.figure()
    plt.show()
    loss_list = []


    for epoch_idx in range(num_epochs):
        x, y = generate_data()
        _current_state = np.zeros((batch_size, state_size))

        print('New data, epoch', epoch_idx)

        for batch_idx in range(num_batches):
            start_idx = batch_idx * truncated_backprop_length
            end_idx = start_idx * truncated_backprop_length

            batchX = x[:,start_idx:end_idx]
            batchY = y[:,start_idx:end_idx]

            _total_loss, _train_step, _current_state, _predictions_series = sess.run(
            [total_loss, train_step, current_state, prediction_series],
            feed_dict={
                batchX_placeholder:batchX,
                batchY_placeholder:batchY,
                init_state:_current_state
            })

            loss_list.append(_total_loss)

            if batch_idx%100 == 0:
                print('Step ', batch_idx, ' Loss ', _total_loss)
                plot(loss_list, _predictions_series, batchX, batchY)

plt.iof()
plt.show()
```

I'm struggling to fix the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-1c187b75429b> in <module>()
     25                 batchX_placeholder:batchX,
     26                 batchY_placeholder:batchY,
---> 27                 init_state:_current_state
     28             })
     29 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    893     try:
    894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
    896       if run_metadata:
    897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1102                 'Cannot feed value of shape %r for Tensor %r, '
   1103                 'which has shape %r'
-> 1104                 % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
   1105           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
   1106             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (5, 0) for Tensor 'Placeholder_6:0', which has shape '(5, 15)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the shape of your batchX (also batchY) is not simillar to the shape of batchX_placeholder(batchY_placeholder). You can verify this by,

```
print(np.shape(batchX)) 
print(np.shape(batchX_placeholder))
```

Hope this helps.